# How to find All Messenger Registered in a Phone Number

Tags: java, android, phone-number, messenger

How Can Find All Messenger (WhatsApp,viber,Line,Telegram,instagram,Kik,And others) Registered in a specific Phone Number ?
I Must Have API of That Messengers ? Or Connect To the They Servers ?

Comment: What exactly is a "messenger"?

Comment: Are you trying to get phone number from app? by in-app id? Because if that is the case you won't be able to... Since they if they have any clue about making application would store it in their database.